# Writing to CSV from an Excel file thats been filtered

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am VERY new to using Python but am trying to teach this old dog new tricks.

The goal of this program is to search through an excel workbook containing multiple sheets, pull only the line items in the search, and give an output that lists the unit name and the returned search items.  It currently goes to a text file with an output for each unit like below:

In PILGRIMS PRD LV OAK (COMPASS-20098) the following items are not approved or pose risk of increased product cost 
                       Description    Brand Quantity Total Price
115  POTATO AU GRATIN CLASSIC CASS  SYS CLS     3 cs     $162.69
135             POTATO PEARL EXCEL  SYS CLS     2 cs     $123.48
149          HAM DICED .25 IN CUBE  FARMLND     1 cs      $24.95
150      PIZZA CHEESE ROUND 5 BULK    TONYS     1 cs      $45.58
154     SAUCE ALFREDO POUCH GLUTFR  STOUFER     1 cs      $47.87

In the following code, I would like to be able to have the output go to a csv file (or multiple csv files) or an excel file (it could be each unit is a worksheet with the search find listed) instead of a text file with the same output information (i.e. name of the unit, and the search items in the columns).

```
import os
import openpyxl
import csv


sheet_data = []   
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('ProductFrequency 092719_021020 by Unit.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

recordDict = {}

for i in range(9, ws.max_row+1):
    itemNum=ws['A'+str(i)].value
    description=ws['B'+str(i)].value
    quantity=ws['H'+str(i)].value

    recordDict.setdefault(itemNum,{})
    recordDict[itemNum][description] = quantity
    #print(itemNum, description, quantity)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100000)


resultsFile = open('Results_UNIT_092719_021020.txt', 'w')
resultsFile.close()
c = csv.writer(open("Results_UNIT_092719_021020.csv", 'w'))


count=0


while count < 78:

    df = pd.read_excel('ProductFrequency 092719_021020 by Unit.xlsx', sheet_name=count, usecols=[0,1,2,7,8,9])
    unitName = df.iloc[0,0]


    df = pd.read_excel('ProductFrequency 092719_021020 by Unit.xlsx', sheet_name=count, skiprows=8, usecols=[0,1,2,7])
    df = df.fillna(value="")

    new_df = df.loc[(df['Dist #'].str.contains('4014320')) |(df['Description'].str.contains('ALFREDO')) | (df['Description'].str.contains('CARNITAS')) | (df['Description'].str.contains('PORK CHOP'))  | (df['Brand'].str.contains('AUSTBLU')) | (df['Brand'].str.contains('CMBLRSV')) | (df['Description'].str.contains('GRAVY SAUSAGE COUNTRY RTU')) | (df['Description'].str.contains('SCRATCH RDY')) | (df['Description'].str.contains('BEEF ROAST POT')) | (df['Description'].str.contains('SALISBURY')) |  (df['Description'].str.contains('FC')) |  (df['Description'].str.contains('BRAISED')) |  (df['Description'].str.contains('TROPICAL')) | (df['Brand'].str.contains('STCLAIR') | (df['Brand'].str.contains('AUBONPN')))]
    resultsFile = open('Results_UNIT_092719_021020.txt', 'a')
    resultsFile.write('In '+unitName+' the following items are not approved \n')
    resultsFile.write(str(new_df)+'\n')
    resultsFile.write('\n')
    resultsFile.write('\n')

    resultsFile.close()


    print('In '+unitName+' the following items are not approved'+'\n\n')
    print(new_df)
    print('\n')

    count +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: CSV (comma-separated values) do not have any "real" formatting. Therefore, there is no filtering (or "hidden" data) of any sort, and also there are no "sheets". It's really just plain data with commas in between, e.g.

```
"
a,b,c
d,e,f
....
"
```

If this does not help with your problem, please explain what you are trying to achieve in more detail (maybe give an example of the desired output).